# Code compiles etc. but just hangs on run

Tags: c

My program is meant to parse through a text file, extract relevant data and then save it in a SQL table. I compile it like so..

```
  gcc -o parse parse.c -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient_r
```

then I run it like so...

```
  ./parse > tweets.rss
```

But it just hangs. it doesn't print any printf's I put in to debug. Whats wrong? here is my code...

http://pastebin.com/3R45zyMp

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Try a debugger like gdb.

Comment: Why dont you use any IDE and debug live rather than putting printfs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are specifying that it should write to tweets.rss instead of read from it.  Since your program reads from STDIN as the first thing it does and you don't supply any input, why would you expect any output?

Try:

```
./parse < tweets.rss
```

Comment: Thanks, that got the file started but it doesn't go inside the loops :S any idea why?

Comment: @Aidan - check to make sure that tweets.rss still contains input.  It was probably overwritten (with nothing) the first time you tried to run your program with the output redirected to it.  Also, see @chrisharris' answer -- your conjuntions should be && not ||, i.e., it's not a space and not a tab and not a newline and not a >, therefore it must be something that I am interested in.

Answer (score 5):

The following is going to loop for ever.

```
while(c!= ' ' || c != '\t' || c != '\n' || c != '>'){
    c = getchar(); //Get a new char
    test[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

c can only be equal to one of them, so the condition will always be true.

Comment: +1 `c` can't be equal to all of those characters at the same time so that when one of the subconditions is false, the others are necessarily true making the entire expression true.